# Добавить кнопку "В корзину" в WordPress (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня сайт на WordPress с использованием WooCommerce. Как мне добавить кнопку в сетку раздела "Похожие товары"? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, который я вставил - это grid(сетка) для "Похожие товары"

```
<?php
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id ),
) );

$slider_args = array(
    'title' =>__('Related Products', 'xstore')
);

etheme_create_slider($args, $slider_args);
?>
```

Comment: Кнопка "Купить" должна быть в стандартном выводе карточки товара. Скорее всего, ее вывод подавлен вашей темой (etheme?). Посмотрите в браузере html, может, там и есть кнопка, но у неё свойство display: none; Более точно ответить трудно - надо видеть вашу тему.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в вашей теме где-то убрали вывод кнопки, примерно таким кодом:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
```

Удалите эту строку.